# how to get wifi channel for my network and nearby networks in Mac/Iphone?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mac, wireless-router

I ran a wireless diagnostics at my Mac. The report summary contains "crowded wi-fi channel". The report mentions couple other things like "wi-fi network is operating on channels that are being used by several other Wi-Fi networks", but nothing really detailed. I know that restarting my router could possibly improve it, but I'm rather curious to see a more detailed report. For example, which channel does my router use? which other channels are being used by some nearby routers, etc.

Any tools/apps/scripts you could suggest to get a more detailed summary about wi-fi channels usage?

- for Mac
- for Iphone

free tools/apps are preferable, but any option is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Mac, use

```
airport -s
```

from a terminal to see all networks, and

```
airport -I
```

for information about the network you are currently connected to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your question (although you didn't ask for it):

Usually in the setup of your router will see the channel it is using (if it's on automatic) and which channels are used by other devices as well. And as a bonus, you are at the right place to change the channel if it's not set to automatic.

Comment: thanks. I had the exact that question, but didn't want to include too man sub-questions into one.

there is some linux running on my router. Do you mean any specific commands (how to see or set up channels from the linux)?

Comment: That depends on your router and what exactly it is running. For one time settings, I usually prefer the web GUI. But yes you could connect a terminal session as well if your router allows that (if I understood you correctly)